# jQuery Sticky Header

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I am trying to implement a Sticky Header for a section of my website like this [demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/PersistantHeaders/)

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

But the Stickyness is not flowing thru to the whole of the container and i get a empty space in my layout.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/

[image]

Comment: could you post a fiddle with some demo html and with js you have so far, so we have something to play around with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing you are missing the CSS to fix the floatingHeader. That will fix your menu you will have to dig deeper on the empty space

```css
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

The demo did not cover the css part

Comment: :D okay not i got that working. Now i need to hack the Code to make it work with already existing sticky header i had deactivated. Any idea how to make it Sticky 95px below.

Comment: With that much going on I would scap all that js and use this plugin. Works like a charm http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ (not mine btw)

Comment: any quick fix for this. Just to get done with. since i wont be using the same effect any where else :D

Answer (score 3):

## Dynamic Sticky Header

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Enter Your Class or ID
    var $stickyMenu = jQuery('.main-nav');

    var stickyNavTop = jQuery($stickyMenu).offset().top;

    //Get Height of Navbar Div
    var navHeight = jQuery($stickyMenu).height();

    var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) { 
            jQuery($stickyMenu).addClass('sticky');
            jQuery('html').css('padding-top', navHeight + 'px')
        } else {
            jQuery($stickyMenu).removeClass('sticky');
            jQuery('html').css('padding-top', '0')
        }
    };

    stickyNav();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});
```

Just add this section to your footer and add the Menu class.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cybentizen/Lxrn3nkL/

Comment: This is the better answer because it adds padding to the outer container (in this case the html tag) equal to the height of the sticky container, so it does not "jump" down the page when applying the sticky class.

Comment: No doubt, this is perfect solution for sticky header.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see any class which has following css attributes.

```
position:fixed and top:0
```

I guess you should try to add those attributes in this

```
.floatingHeader
```